# prevent solution from being simplified

Tags: z3

I want to the solution got back from z3 without simplification using `let` statements.

For example if  I give the following:

```
(declare-const x Int)
  (elim-quantifiers (exists ((x.1 Int)) 
    (and (or (and (= (- x.1 2) 0) (<= (- x.1 9) 0)) 
             (and (or (= (- x.1 2) 0) (and (<= (- x.1 4) 0) 
                                      (and (<= (- 4 x.1) 0) 
                                           (<= (- x.1 11) 0)))) (<= (- x.1 9) 0))) (= (- (+ x.1 2) x) 0))))
```

I get back the solution as:

```
(let ((a!1 (and (or (and (<= x 4) (>= x 4)) (and (<= x 6) (>= x 6) (<= x 13)))
                (<= x 11))))
    (or (and (<= x 4) (>= x 4) (<= x 11)) a!1))
```

Is there a way to tell Z3 not to extract some complex expressions into a let statement ? It will be easier for me to parse the result if I get the answer flat without let statement.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

We can set the following options to prevent the Z3 pretty printer from using `let`s

```
(set-option :pp-min-alias-size 1000000)
(set-option :pp-max-depth      1000000)
```

Any big number will do the trick.

We have to keep in mind that it may not be feasible to display some formulas that contain a lot of shared sub-expressions when we avoid the `let`s. Internally, Z3 stores the formulas as DAGs instead of Trees. If we do not use the `let`s, the pretty-print of such formulas may be exponentially bigger than their internal representation. So, we should not abuse the options above.

Comment: Great. Could you accept the answer? Thus, other users will know that the answer solves the problem posted in your question. Thanks

Comment: Can these options also be set using the C API, and if yes, how?

Comment: Yes, they can. See http://z3.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest#examples/c++/example.cpp, it has examples that set parameters such as `:pp-decimal`.

Answer (score 0):

I am using `z3-4.5.0` and looks like the options names have changed a little. If `pp-max-depth` did not work for you, try `pp.max_depth` and `pp.min_alias_size`.

I am using the Java API and the following worked with me

```
com.microsoft.z3.Global.setParameter("pp.min_alias_size", "1000000");
com.microsoft.z3.Global.setParameter("pp.max_depth", "1000000");
```